# Почему в посимвольном отображении string в php возникают кракозябры

Tags: php

Файл в кодировке utf-8. В английских символах все в порядке. Например, "Hello" 
символы отображаются корректно. Отображение проверяется в Chrome

```
   <?php 
      $var = "Привет";
      echo $var;
      $i = mb_strlen($var); 
      $it = 0;
      while($i != 0){
         echo $var{$it};
         $it++;
         $i--;
         echo "<br>";
      }
```

Comment: У меня нормально выполнился в консоли

Comment: Потому что `$var{$it}` берет байты, а не символы.

Comment: А как решить эту проблему?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-substr.php и берете с ее помощью по 1 символу.

Comment: @Visman спасибо за подробные пояснения